# Excel: sort column with mixed numbers and letters?

Tags: excel

I am working of the dataset in Excel that I obtained from an experiment. Since I needed some ratings (and I wanted the raters to be blind) I completely randomized the answers and now I can't put them back in order!
This is what I have:

1A

38R

22R

7A

41R

64A

etc...

And this is what I need in the end:

1A

2A

3A

...

99R

100R

101R

Thank you!

Comment: To sort it without vba you will need to add 0s to the front of the numbers so each text string has the same number of characters.  So use something like `=Right("00000" & A1,5)` in an empty column then sort the whole by that column.  Then you can delete the column.

Comment: Check out [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214282), I think that's what you'd want, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created two new columns (B and C in this case, as in the other example posted).

I have typed LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1) in column B to get the number; then =RIGHT(A1,1) in column C to get the letter; finally I can sort by B and C.

Comment: If the answer was already posted you should have accepted it, rather than copy that answer into your own.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get your desired output by sorting alphabetically, because `100R` would come before `2A`.

If your values will always be in the format of a number followed by a single character and will be at most 5 characters long, you can use @Scott Craner's formula `=RIGHT("00000"&A1,5)` to pad the left of your value with "0" so that you can alphabetize correctly. `100R` will become `0100R`. `2A` will become `0002A`. These will now alphabetize correctly.

Now you can simply sort your range by column B ascending alphabetically.

If you need more characters, just add as many zeroes as characters to the formula, and change the `5` in the formula to your new number of characters.

[Here is an example excel file.](http://www.filedropper.com/sorttest)

**INPUT**

```
+---+-----+-------+
|   | A   | B     |
+---+-----+-------+
| 1 | 1A  | 0001A |
+---+-----+-------+
| 2 | 38R | 0038R |
+---+-----+-------+
| 3 | 22R | 0022R |
+---+-----+-------+
| 4 | 7A  | 0007A |
+---+-----+-------+
| 5 | 41R | 0041R |
+---+-----+-------+
| 6 | 64A | 0064A |
+---+-----+-------+
```

**RESULT**

```
+---+-----+-------+
|   | A   | B     |
+---+-----+-------+
| 1 | 1A  | 0001A |
+---+-----+-------+
| 2 | 7A  | 0007A |
+---+-----+-------+
| 3 | 22R | 0022R |
+---+-----+-------+
| 4 | 38R | 0038R |
+---+-----+-------+
| 5 | 41R | 0041R |
+---+-----+-------+
| 6 | 64A | 0064A |
+---+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately I get a #NAME! error.

Comment: Assuming you only ever have one letter at the end of your value, and it is no more than 5 characters long, @Scott Craner 's formula is simpler. I have modified my answer to use this, and have included a link to an example excel file.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Yes there is only one letter at the end of the value.